# Storing list of security questions in a table in the database - need access as anonymous?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, forms-authentication

I have a project using Forms Authentication. When a user signs up, they need to set a security question with their account. I want to store the list of security questions in the database so that an Admin person in the future can control this list... add questions, retire questions, etc... The admin piece is working fine, but is is secured, meaning my business layer is restricted to authenticated users, using, among other things Principal Permission attributes.

The problem is that on the actual Sign Up form, the users are anonymous. I can't wrap my head around how allow retrieve access to this list of questions for anonymous users.

Comment: Your business layer needs to allow anonymous access for anything done in the signup process. Or create an alternate path (parallel data layer) just for those users.

Comment: I think I am going to go with 'parallel data layer just for those users'. How do I mark a comment as the accepted answer?

Comment: You can't accept a comment as an answer. I'll make it an answer and then you can accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your business layer needs to allow anonymous access for anything done in the signup process. Or create an alternate path (parallel data layer) just for those users.

The danger with the second method is you may end up duplicating code, which would be bad for maintenance.

Comment: Going with option 2, parallel data layer. Only functions that need to happen for unauthorized users will be accesable from that layer. The respository is where the problem is, and I believe I can just inherit from my main repsoitory with an 'Unauthenticated' repsoitory that only accesses what I need.

Comment: I am using Bounded Contexts, so this will ust be another context, bound by the unathorized nature of access ot it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your setup correctly, do the following:

1. Move your `PrincipalPermission` attributes from the class to the specific methods that are "Admin only".
2. Create a new method, ie Retrieve, without any `PrincipalPermission` attribute.